# How may I add a Scale to the left side of a Graph in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: debugging, graph, scale, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

## Is there a Way to get a scale from zero to the max value used in the linked Table?

Hey there, im using Libreoffice calc to make up some bloodsugar analysis.
I got the problem now, that i made a graph and this graph does not contain a scale on the left side.

I need to find a way to add this.

Can you help me please?

**Ill upload the document to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xugfhh8ub1iovm/BZ-Werte.ods?dl=1)
[image] and make a screenshot to explain what i mean**

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please go to [**Format-Axis-Y Axis**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/shared/guide/chart_axis.html)-Label tab and check if the [**Show labels**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/schart/01/05020201.html) checkbox is enabled

Comment: thanks it worked easy!!! i just did not find the option :D